# All in one IE conditional function

Tags: arrays, internet-explorer, if-statement

Trying to create and "all-in-one" IE conditional function.

Pretty much I'd like to be able to do the following:

1. If no variable is passed then check for IE in general
2. Pass it 1 version of IE and check for that
3. Pass an array of versions and check for either of those versions

I am having trouble with the last part which would check for multiple versions of IE. For instance, if I only wanted to target IE versions 7 and 8.

```
function is_ie( $versions = '' ) {

    if( $versions == '' ) {
        if ( isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) && strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'MSIE' ) !== false)
            return true;
    }

    $versions = ( is_array($versions) ) ? $versions : array($versions);
    $operand = '';

    foreach( $versions as $version ) {
        if ( isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) && strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'MSIE ' . $version . '.' ) !== false) {
            $operand = true; break;
        }
    }

    return ($operand) ? true : false;

}
```

Also, is there any sacrifice on performance with this function? Saying I used it a couple times throughout a site. Wondering if I should set some type of GLOBAL variable and check for that instead?

Comment: You should not browser sniff this is going to lead to many, many problems. You should feature detect instead and act accordingly.

Comment: What kind of problems? Can you please explain further?

Comment: The simplest is the millions of web sites that identify Internet Explorer and then assume it is 6-8 years out of date and does not support modern standards. They then provide buggy CSS and JavaScript to the client and everyone assumes it is Internet Explorer that is broken.

Comment: Browser update over time, things that were not even thought of 6 years ago are now standards and supported by IE. If you feature detect you will know if the browser supports the actual API you need and if not then you download a polyfil for example. Much cleaner and gives your web site a longer life.

Comment: Thank you for explaining, I appreciate it. I totally agree. However, I am still looking to create a function like this for other purposes.